# Can latexmk -pvc re-compile when a dependency is modified?

Tags: latexmk, live-preview

When I run `latexmk -pdf -deps`, I get a list of files which are my main .tex depedencies.

When I run `latexmk -pdf -pvc`, I'd like latexmk to re-compile when the main file *or a dependency* is modified. But this is not the case. It re-compile only if the main file is modified.

Is there a way to correct it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, latexmk does do a recompilation when a dependent file is modified.  This is actually mentioned near the beginning of the latexmk documentation (specifically the third paragraph).  I rely on that feature regularly in my uses of latexmk.

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. Its seems something has gone wrong in my config as its was ok afterwards. It works fine.Thanks !